# Django Model for players

Tags: python, django

I'm working on a django website that can allow me to display some information about players and matches for a game.

There will be multiple matches and multiple players. The problem I'm having is that I'm not sure if this is what I should be doing:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    player_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    matches = models.ManyToMany(Match)

class Matches(models.Model):
    match_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    players = models.ManyToMany(Player)
```

or I should be doing:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    player_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)

class Matches(models.Model):
    match_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    players = models.ManyToMany(Player)
```

A player can be in multiple matches, and a match can contain multiple players, which is why I'm a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

You should define the relation in only one of the models, so the second example is the correct one.

In the first one (you have a typo there that should be `Matches` by the way) you are creating two separate M2M relations between the two models that you don't want to have in your case.

On an unrelated note, you *don't* need to to have `player_id` and `match_id` columns as Django will automatically create `id` columns for your models.

Comment: Thank you for the help! What is the difference between the first one and second one? As in 2 separate M2M relations, aren't they just referencing each other? For `player_id` and `match_id`, what if the ids don't start at 0/1, is that fine? Sorry I'm new to django in general :\

Comment: @Rohinder In the second you are creating two separate relations, they are _not_ referencing each other. One could be, for example, used for indicating which players played in which matches and the other for indicating which players were substitute players in which matches.

Comment: @Rohinder Regarding the `id`s, you should generally don't care about them and leave management to Django, unless you have an existing database with data in it.

Answer (score 0):

You definetelly have to use [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ManyToManyField), you can add it only to one model:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    player_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    matches = models.ManyToMany(Match)

class Matches(models.Model):
    match_id = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

After declaring models, Player objects have access to their related Matches objects in next way:

```
player.matches.all()
```

Matches objects have access to their related Player objects in next way:

```
match.player_set.all()
```

See article  [Many-to-many relationships, Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), there are plenty of use full information of how to dial with ManyToMany relations in Django.

Comment: Thank you! Should I put the M2M in the Player, or Matches? Will it make a difference?

Comment: @Rohinder Both models would have access to each other, so my  it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Rohinder iv'e added snippets of how to access related objects from each model.

Comment: Thank you! Since a match can have a list of players, how would I save them? Like, player 1 2 3 4 5 are in match 10, how would I make it so match 10 contains these players? Same for the other way around, a player in multiple games.

Comment: @Rohinder Create `player` and then call `match.player_set.add(player)`

Comment: Thank you! I'm guessing that to remove a player I just do `match.player_set.remove(player)`?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will solve your model structure for your project.

```
class TimeStamped(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Player(TimeStamped):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    extra_info = models.TextField()
    matches = models.ManyToManyField('Match')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Match(TimeStamped):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    extra_info = models.TextField()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Matches'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

The `TimeStamped` model is a good idea for every project you build. If you are using Python 3 then replace `__unicode__` with `__str__`. Don't use plural in model names. Use `verbose_name_plural`, that is the convention in my opinion. It seems like you might have a problem with query players from a `Match` instance. Read the documentation for a detailed info on that. If you can't find that post here. Since this post is not about the querysets so I skipped that part.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely right for this scenario, ManyToMany relation is required to setup in DB.

id is the default field in Django model if you are not providing any other primary key. And ID is incremental. As per my opinion, Following models are enough to satisfy your scenario.

```
class Player(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Match(modles.Model):
    player = models.ManyToMany(Player, related_name="matches")
```

According to above model sample, you can accessing matches of one player and players who played a single match.

```
match = Match.objects.get(id=1)
print match.player.all() # It will print all players for match of id 1

player = Player.objects.get(id=1)
print player.matches
```